# How to make a div transparent and float it over an image?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div transparent and move it over an image. Here's the sample code of html and css:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .head {
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 346px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        h2 {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">
            <h2>Logo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result of the output: 
[image]

But I want it like this:
[image]

Can anyone please help me in this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide `position: absolute` to `.head`

So your code becomes:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.head {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 346px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
h2 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="head">
    <h2>Logo</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answers were posted at the same time. Did not see the other answer.